# How many aspects can you hold in your inventory in Diablo 4?

Tags: diablo-iv

How many aspects can you hold in your inventory in Diablo 4? Is there a max?
I can't find anything on the internet about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aspect tab in the inventory can store 22 aspects

[image: Aspect inventory showing 22 slots]

Comment: Thanks, was hoping it would be more.

Comment: Completing dungeons will unlock them in the Codex for you and also yields a stronger version

Comment: The Codex of Power only holds some of all the aspects in the game. And using an aspect from the Codex will always be the lowest possible roll.

Comment: @trappski If you know which ones are not in the Codex, do add them to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

While there are only 22 slots available in the inventory, you can also store these aspects in your stash.

The stash holds 50 items, 5 rows of 10. More tabs can also be purchased for 100k, 200k, and 300k; the max is 4 tabs.

Historically Blizzard has increased the stash size slightly as the game progresses, so we may see another tab available at some point, but this is for the most part what we get.

In total, this means you could hold 200 aspects in your stash and 22 in your inventory, if you were going to be intense about it.

One thing to consider is just space management. Keep track of your aspects to make sure that you aren't duplicating them, or storing ones which are not really useful for your play style, or storing ones which may be imprinted from the codex.

This is more of an end game issue, and will probably begin to present as an inventory management problem around level 70. I would suggest to make sure you are only keeping the high roll aspects, and also to make more use of the blacksmith's salvage utility for crafting mats.